# Clipboard Copy Event losing scope inside Subscribe event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom

Ok I am trying to copy text to the clipboard in angular 2. This is my function on button press. It goes out to the database to return a bunch of data. I format this into readable strings and copy it to the clipboard automatically.

The problem is it works fine outside of the subscribe event but if it is inside the subscribe event then nothing gets copied to the clipboard.

So what is happening here is once the event is unsubscribed the window loses scope and the clipboard becomes empty. I tested in debug mode with var clipboardContent = window.getSelection().toString(); in the subscribe event the content is set properly but soon as the event leaves the content disappears

```
getAllUserDetail() {

 

   const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');

  this._service.getUserDetails(this.model)

  .subscribe(jentries => {

    const entryText = jentries;

    selBox.style.position = 'fixed';

    selBox.style.left = '0';

    selBox.style.top = '0';

    selBox.style.opacity = '0';

    selBox.value = sqlString;

 

    document.body.appendChild(selBox);

    selBox.focus();

    selBox.select();

 

    document.execCommand('copy');

    document.body.removeChild(selBox);

}
```

but this works but not what I need

```
 getAllUserDetail() {

 

        const entryText = 'TEST DATA;

        selBox.style.position = 'fixed';

        selBox.style.left = '0';

        selBox.style.top = '0';

        selBox.style.opacity = '0';

        selBox.value = sqlString;

 

        document.body.appendChild(selBox);

        selBox.focus();

        selBox.select();

 

        document.execCommand('copy');

        document.body.removeChild(selBox);

 

 

    this._service.getUserDetails(this.model)

      .subscribe(jentries => { });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to call my subscribe event from another function and assign the entries to a class variable.

Then when the user hit the button i copied the text to the clipboard that way by using the already assigned class variable.

It wasn't what I was looking for but it got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call another method out of the subscription and hand in the sqlString as a parameter.

```
getAllUserDetail() {
  this._service.getUserDetails(this.model).subscribe(jentries => {
      this.applyValues(jentries);
   });
}

applyValues(sqlString: string) {

    const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');

    selBox.style.position = 'fixed';

    selBox.style.left = '0';

    selBox.style.top = '0';

    selBox.style.opacity = '0';

    selBox.value = sqlString;



    document.body.appendChild(selBox);

    selBox.focus();

    selBox.select();

    document.execCommand('copy');

    document.body.removeChild(selBox);

}
```

Comment: This isn't working either. So what is happening here is once the event is unsubscribed the window loses scope. I tested in debug mode with var clipboardContent = window.getSelection().toString(); in the subscribe event the content is set properly but soon as the event leaves the content dissappears